# Getting an array from POST in django issue

Tags: django

Client side:

```
$fk_fields=[];
$fk_fields.push({'a':1,'b':2});
$fk_fields.push({'a':3,'b':4});

$data = {'fk_fieldss': $fk_fields};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../getFormMetaData/",
        cache:false,
        data: $data,
        success: createZoomDialog,
        error: displayAjaxError
    });
```

Server side:

```
fk_fields=request.POST.getlist('fk_fieldss')
print fk_fields
```

What ever i try no success. Always i get an empty string while other non aray values are ok. if i do `print request.POST` i see values in post but i cannot get array from that. Why?

### UPDATE

Here is how look's like print request.POST:

```
<QueryDict: {u'fk_fieldss[0][b]': [u'2'], u'fk_fieldss[1][b]': [u'4'], u'fk_fieldss[0][a]': [u'1'], u'fk_fieldss[1][a]': [u'3']}>
```

### SOLUTION

client side:

```
$data = {'fk_fieldss': JSON.stringify($fk_fields)};
```

server side:

```
fk_fields = json.loads(request.POST['fk_fieldss'])
```

Comment: Try: `getlist('fk_fieldss[]')`

Comment: Nope, still the same...

Comment: what do you see when you do `print request.POST` ?

Comment: Try this request.POST.lists() or even request.POST.values()

Comment: With lists() i get: [(u'fk_fieldss[0][b]', [u'2']), (u'fk_fieldss[1][b]', [u'4']), (u'fk_fieldss[0][a]', [u'1']), (u'fk_fieldss[1][a]', [u'3'])] but now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode your array into json string on js side and then decode it in django:

in js

```
data: JSON.stringify($data),
```

then in django:

```
fk_fields = json.loads(request.POST)['fk_fieldss']
```

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: now i have problem with csrf token... he is in $data but now data is json object...